# I'm trying to make a website but server won't start

Tags: server, loading

I'm trying to make a website and when I start the use the command `rails s` it says this:

```
<code>
$ rails s 
=> Booting WEBrick 
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options 
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
[2016-04-15 15:19:20] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 
[2016-04-15 15:19:20] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32] 
[2016-04-15 15:19:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5892 port=3000 
</code>
```

It doesn't go past that it just gets stuck on that i've port fowarded 3000 and added it to the firewalls exceptions list and still no go it works on my dads connection but not on mine.

These are the commands I use prior to entering rails:

```
s , rails new instagram_app , cd_instagramapp.
```

Answer (score 0):

After run command "rails s". Just open a browser window and navigate to http://localhost:3000

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server

Comment: Oh lord! thank you man xD i've been stuck on this local host problem for like a month and a half! Thank you so much!!!!! :D